# SCSS Lint plugin for PHPStorm triggers errors in gulp-compass task

Tags: sass, phpstorm, gulp-compass

### The Setup:

- Using scss-lint plugin for IntelliJ-based IDEs (PHPStorm)
  http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7530?pr=phpStorm
- A gulp-compass task, part of a larger Gulp build process, that watches my sass (scss) dir.
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass

**NOTE:**

- OS: Windows 8
- both tools work as expected.

### The Situation:

With the scss-lint inspection active, any kind of typing activity in the editor (including simply typing a whitespace) triggers the gulp-compass task, and the terminal for said task returns *'file not found'* errors along the following line:

```
[10:53:34] Starting 'dev-compass'...
[10:53:34] Finished 'dev-compass' after 3.58 ms
[10:53:36] File not found: E:/projects/xf/src/sass/blog_scsslint_tmp8349313806557714816.scss
[10:53:36] 

[10:53:36] { [Error: Compass failed]
  message: 'Compass failed',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-compass',
  __safety: { toString: [Function] } }
[BS] 1 file changed (blog.css)

[10:53:46] Starting 'dev-compass'...
[10:53:46] Finished 'dev-compass' after 15 ms
    write src/styles.group/blog.css

[BS] 1 file changed (blog.css)
```

*Note: this 'error' doesn't prevent the task to perform; when I make actual changes to the .scss source files, the .css are generated properly.*

Apparently, either SCSS Lint itself and/or the PHPStorm plugin generate temporary files when the inspection occurs, and promptly removes them -- presumably when the inspection finishes.

As it does so in the same directory that's being watched by the gulp-compass task... These two end up playing NYSMNYD (*now you see me, now you don't*).

I was hoping I could either:

- set my SCSS Lint configuration file to force a different path for the temporary files, or,
- set my gulp-compass task to ignore files based on a pattern such as `*scsslint_tmp*.scss`

But so far, I haven't found any way to do either of these.

I suppose it could be seen as just a 'cosmetic' error, since both tools do produce the desired outputs, but it results in unnecessary processing, and by filling my terminal with 'bogus' errors just make it more confusing to spot the genuine ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't made any progress in finding a fix since I posted this question, and since the gulp task actually failed while further testing, I implemented a kind of a dirty hack:  
- renamed all my scss partials with a distinct suffix i.e. _colors.scss to _colors-xf.scss, _normalize.scss to _normalize-xf.scss, etc  
- changed the gulp-compass task configuration, listing explicitly the main files to process and all -xf.scss files, like so:  
`"scssSourceFiles": [  
      "src/sass/blog.scss",  
      "src/sass/**/*-xf.scss",  
      "src/sass/vendors/*vendors.scss"  
    ]`

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/idok/scss-lint-plugin/issues/13

Comment: Well spotted, @LazyOne thanks. That said, I've invested too much time in Gulp to switch to Grunt, so until they decide to fix this, I shall look into an equivalent 'ignore' on the Gulp side. In the meantime, my little workaround lets me move on with my current project.